# Newbie SQL Table Design

Tags: sql, sqlite

Watch out, learning sql newbie. I would like to create 2 simple tables.

products: id | product_name

order_table: id | buyer_name | purchased_products

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  product_name TEXT
  );

CREATE TABLE order_table (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  buyer_name TEXT,
  purchased_products NUMERIC ARRAY
  );
```

Currently the link is numeric, but this would require the report generation to know that purchased_products is referring to the products table. Is it possible to define that the purchased_products must be referring to the products?

Note: this is sqlite3,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the field `purchased_products` and create one more table, like this:

order_product: id | order_id | product_id

Now, you should declare that `order_id` is a foreign key referring to the field `id` of the table `order_table`, and that product_id does the same for `products`.